# Block website access via browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a windows application which shows web page hosted in a website. Because of confidentiality, I don't want to show URL to the user. As this website is hosted on IIS and so user can access website directly through browser if he/she knows URL.

How can I block access of website via browser but not through windows application?

P.S. this website is third pary product hosted on my machine and I cannot do any code change into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make any code changes to the website, it will not be possible to block access based on which system is calling the URL using IIS alone.

One approach would be to put the webserver behind a firewall and implement an authentication / authorization mechanism between your application and the firewall.